# using typedef to wrap functions

Tags: c++, function, pointers, wrapper, typedef

One of my teachers use this type declaration:

```
typedef void (*SortFunction)(int a[], int n);
```

to create a type that can hold a pointer to a function
and that can be used to call that function later on in a program.

I also know that to pass a function as a parameter you have to 
wrap the function name in parenthesis and wrap the function's
parameters in parenthesis after the function name as well like so

```
function someFunction( (anotherfunction)(type arg1, type arg2,...)){
  ...
}
```

What I want to know is why must you wrap a function in parenthesis like this? is this a built in function of most c++ compilers or is it simply a trick that we programmers use
in order to enable functions as arguments within our code? also, why does "SortFunction"
in the typedef statement need to be referenced, why can't the variable you use to utilize SortFunction just hold the function instead of pointing to it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing special about function arguments.  Whenever you declare a function pointer (as a local variable, global variable, class member variable, function parameter, typedef, etc.), it's always declared like so:

```
return_type (*var_name)(T1 param1, T2 param2, /* etc. */ );
//           ^
//           |
// This * is very important!
```

Where `var_name` is the name of the function pointer variable.  The reason the parentheses are needed around `*var_name` is due to operator precedence: without the parentheses, the `*` (indicating that something's a pointer) would match with the function's return type, and instead you'd get something like a return type of `int*` (pointer to `int`) instead of plain `int`.

You can't pass a function as an argument because functions are not first-class objects in C and C++.  The only way to pass a function is my passing a pointer to the function.

Answer (score 1):

*"I also know that to pass a function as a parameter you have to wrap the function name in parenthesis..."* You "know " incorrectly.

In order to pass function pointer as a parameter you don't have to wrap the name in parentheses. For example, this will work perfectly fine

```
void foo(int i) {
} 

void bar(void f(int)) {
  f(5);
}

int main() {
  bar();
}
```

In the above example function `bar` receives a pointer to function `foo` as a parameter and calls `foo` through that pointer, passing `5` as an argument. As you can see, function name  `f` in the parameter declaration is *not* wrapped into parentheses.

In this case, once again, the type of parameter `f` is actually a *pointer* to a function, even though it is not explicitly declared as a pointer. When function type is used in function parameter declarations, it is automatically implicitly "replaced" with function pointer type by the compiler.

If you wanted to use the function pointer type explicitly, you have to declare `bar` as

```
void bar(void (*f)(int)) {
  f(5);
}
```

In this case the parentheses in `(*f)` are necessary to assure that the `*` will get bound to `f` and not to `void`. Without parentheses the `void *f(int)` declaration would stand for "function returning `void *`" instead of the desired "pointer to function returning `void`".

Answer (score 0):

It is a matter of syntax. Your first `typedef` defines a type which is a function receiving a vector of `int` and a `int` and returning nothing (`void`).

A variable of type  `SortFunction` will be conceptually as any other variable, although it points to some function. The advantage is that you can change the function it points to and/or call the function dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

> What I want to know is why must you wrap a function in parenthesis like this?

Because there had to be some way to identify a function pointer to the compiler (or rather, the parser) and that way seemed as good as any. In C++11 land, you might use this instead: `std::function<void(std::array<int>&)>` instead.

> is this a built in function of most c++ compilers or is it simply a trick that we programmers use in order to enable functions as arguments within our code?

Function pointers need a little bit of additional magic, and without compiler support they would be very, very inconvenient to use. I'm also reasonably certain that it is in the nature of programming that almost all programmer tricks are ultimately functions of the compiler!

> also, why does "SortFunction" in the typedef statement need to be referenced, why can't the variable you use to utilize SortFunction just hold the function instead of pointing to it?

Hmm. Not totally sure what you mean here. Do you mean "*why does this need to be a `typedef` at all... why couldn't I just write out the whole function pointer prototype in my function arguments*"? Cos you can:

```
void foo(void(*funcptr)()) {}
```

If you meant "*why do function pointers have to point at a function instead of having the code inline*" then for that you need C++11 and lambdas:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

void foo(std::function<void(void)> bar) { bar(); }

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    foo([]() { std::cout << "hi!" << std::endl; });
}
```

(again, special syntax needed for lambdas, `[](){}`, just to tell the parser what is going on)

Comment: Note that context free lambdas can be turned into function pointers implicitly, if I read the latest C++11 standard right.

Comment: @Yakk you may well be right, but neither of the two compilers I have to hand support this. Neither have particularly strong C++11 support, however.

Comment: Yep -- that was, I believe, added pretty late in the standardization cycle.  Or maybe it wasn't added, just considered...